# Rotate Edge to Be Perpendicular to the Ground

Tags: modeling

How can I rotate a diagonal edge, in edit mode, so that it becomes perpendicular to the ground?

Comment: are you talking about an object, or just a edge in edit mode?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying; I am talking about an edge in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I usually do it...

1. Go to **navigation panel** > **Mesh Display** turn on display edge length.
2. Select the vertex point you want to rotate the line on ... (but we DO NOT rotate)
3. **Instead**, Hit <kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>Z</kbd> for the axis you want the point to extrude in and key in the edge length revealed in step 1.
4. Select the diagonal edge and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>

Now you have the new edge perpendicular to the ground.

Hope that helps.